# Variable from another file echoed but not recognized in the script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a variable in a file called *access.txt* located at `/home/ubuntu/pub/access.txt`. The *access.txt* contents looks like this:

```
SFTP_VAR="JHGSYDDUIGUIGUIGUIG"
SQL_VAR="GUIIGGJHGBJHGJHGJH"
```

I have a script file on the same machine that is supposed to read and use this `SFTP_VAR`. I use the `source` statement to mention the location of *access.txt*. Here is the code on my script file.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/ubuntu/pub/access.txt
echo $SFTP_VAR
export SSHPASS=$SFTP_VAR
for f in /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Upstream/Encrypted/* ; 
do 
    echo put "$f"
done | sshpass -e sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss USERNAME@FTP_SERVER_IP:/Import
unset SSHPASS
```

When I run my script, I see the variable in the first `echo`. This means my script can see the file. But the `export` command immediately after the first echo does not seem to recognize my variable. This is when I replace the variable with its real value or:

```
echo 'JHGSYDDUIGUIGUIGUIG'
export SSHPASS='JHGSYDDUIGUIGUIGUIG'
```

The code works fine. What am I missing here and how can I read those variables in the code?

Comment: If the script containing `export` is _executed_ and not _sourced_ the logic would never work

Comment: I don't quite follow. The value in the source file is echoed, but it is not read in the `export` command.

Comment: The value will be exported _Yes_, but the shell in which the variable is exported is killed after script execution, so you need to run in the current shell. See if my answer makes sense

Comment: What do you get if you do `echo "$SSHPASS"` after the export and before the `unset SSHPASS`.

Comment: @123 I get the value I want in echo which is 'JHGSYDDUIGUIGUIGUIG'. I just can't figure out why my `export` statement does not recognize that.

Comment: Dunno then. Check /home/ubuntu/pub/access.txt for carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** During further discussion in the comments it was found to be a problem with the quotes and not with sessions. Changing the double quotes to single quotes in the access.txt file solved it for OP.

I will leave my original answer below.

---

Your question is very poorly worded. I think I see your problem, but I am not sure.

It seems you might have some misunderstandings of how source and export work and how they affect your session. Lets test this:

First create a file with this content and give the path at line 6 of the script:

```
VAR1="value of VAR1"
VAR2="value of VAR2"
```

Then create this script called script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[The variables with the name VAR1 and VAR2 are undefined in out session]"
echo "VAR1: "$VAR1
echo "VAR2: "$VAR2

echo "[Source brings the variables of the file into our session, with them VAR1 and VAR2]"
source /home/X/access.txt

echo "[VAR1 and VAR2 of our session do now have the values specified in the file]"
echo "VAR1: "$VAR1
echo "VAR2: "$VAR2

echo "[A third undefined variable is used - empty]"
echo "VAR3: "$VAR3

echo "[The third variable gets the value of VAR1 and is exported]"
export VAR3=$VAR1

echo "[The third variale is now filled]"
echo "VAR3: "$VAR3

echo "[We unset the variable]"
unset VAR3

echo "[The variable is no longer set]"
echo "VAR3: "$VAR3

echo "[Set it again]"
export VAR3=$VAR1

echo "[Its back now]"
echo "VAR3: "$VAR3
```

I think it covers everything you want to do. Now on to testing:

**First step:**
Just use a normal call on it`bash script.sh`. Then look at the stdout. Everything should be there as is described by the echos.

**Second step:**
Now try `echo $VAR3` from your shell where you previously called the script. It should not print anything. The variables did not hold their values after the script completed.

**Third step:**
Now call the script again with `export script.sh`. Output should look just the way it did in the first step.

**Fourth step:**
Now try `echo $VAR3` again. It will now print the variable.

---

**Why is that?**

Bash is based on different sessions. Things you set after you started your session will not carry over to other open sessions and will be lost after you exit the session.

You can start new sessions by simply typing `bash`. But even this does not solve our problem.

When you call your script you use `bash script.sh`. This actually also starts a new session and then executes your script inside of this session. Not in the one you called it from.

After finishing it exits out of this session leaving behind the set variables. This is why you cant see them by simple using `bash script.sh`

In the third step we used `source` to call the script. This will get the variables into our session and thus we can print the values out.

But this still makes them only temporary as they will go away once we close the session where we sourced the script.

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate and subtle description and tutorial. My code above starts with a `source` command. This is supposed to load the variables into the script. Am I right? But how come I get nothing when I `export` one of my variables even though I `unset` nothing between those two? Aren't my `source` and `export` part of the same session? I have been given loads of messages on what I do/get wrong. But no one has told me what I should fix in my script.

Comment: I don't know if I should small or cry about all these hours wasted. The problem was solved when I changed (") to (') in my `access.txt`. Looking at the time you spent on my question, I really don't mind if you post that as answer.

Comment: Hm, well that's strange. Are you sure those really were double quotes? Maybe there is something wrong with your encoding because it should work with both. I have used double quotes and now tested it with single quotes and no quotes at all. Single quotes work, non do not - as to be expected.
Edit: And of course that's not really time wasted. Now you know you might have to check the type of quotes. That's quite important and I had problems with this before too.

Comment: It can stem from the fact that I write my bash script on a Window and the server is an Ubuntu. But that's also strange because I change the OS type on my Notepad++.

Comment: Yes, check all files you use with an editor on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Put things in double quotes. Your example `SFTP_VAR="JHGSYDDUIGUIGUIGUIG"` should work fine, but try the password "*".

```
#  Incorrect
SFTP_VAR="*"; export SSHPASS=$SFTP_VAR;   echo $SSHPASS
# Correct
SFTP_VAR="*"; export SSHPASS="$SFTP_VAR"; echo "$SSHPASS"
```

Comment: But it worked only when I put things in single quotes!